# OpenCV slow face detection with CCTV Or IP Cam

Tags: python, opencv, machine-learning, image-processing, yolo

When i try to detect face using my laptop or computer web cam it work fine but when i try to detect using IP cam it looks like it take to much time to detect one frame. Is there any solution for this because I also try YOLO. It take more time  than opencv haar cascade

There I have a simple code that detect face and crop than part of frame.

```
cap = cv2.VideoCapture("web_Cam_IP")

cropScal = 25


while(True):
    # Capture frame-by-frame
    for i in range(10): #this loop skip 10 frames if I don't skip frame it looks like it stack there
        ret, frame = cap.read()

    frame = cv2.resize(frame, (0, 0), fx=0.70, fy=0.70)

    # Our operations on the frame come here
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)
    faces = faceCascade.detectMultiScale(gray, scaleFactor=1.02, minNeighbors=5, minSize=(30, 30))


    for (x, y, w, h) in faces:    
        if len(faces) > 0 :
            try:
                img = gray[y-cropScal:y+h+cropScal, x-cropScal:x+w+cropScal]
                img = cv2.resize(img,(200,200))
                img = Image.fromarray(img)
                img.save('images/'+datetime.now().strftime("%d_%m_%Y_%I_%M_%S_%p")+'.png')
            except Exception as e:
                pass
        cv2.rectangle(gray, (x-cropScal, y-cropScal), (x+w+cropScal, y+h+cropScal), (0, 255, 0), 2)



    cv2.imshow('frame',gray)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

# When everything done, release the capture
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Are you using CPU to process the frames? Ideally yolo requires GPU to do the computation. I imagine you are getting 1 fps performance for both web and ip cams? IP cam is definitely slower, due to frame streaming over network.

Comment: Yes I'm using CPU, But this is not YOLO, this is opencv or detection.

Answer (score 0):

You're only scaling the input frames by a factor of 0.70, not to an absolute resolution. It's possible that your IP cam has a higher resolution than your webcam and so the detection requires more time to analyze a larger frame.

Try rescaling the frames to a definite size (eg. 800x600) before the face detection.

Comment: frame = cv2.resize(frame, (800,600)) 
but it  getting delayed, and the display from the camera lags.